# Getting Value from database returning only 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute this query :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 where '1018' in (Content)
```

and this is the content on `Table1` :

[image]

Though my query is returning only the second record.

shouldn't it return all the records ?

Comment: Try something like this. `SELECT * FROM Table1 where Content like '%1018%'`

Comment: but if a row contain this value 101820 for example it will also be returned by this query no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query currently states  `where '1018' in (Content)`

Look at Contents:

```
1018,1020,1021
```

You're saying `where '1018' in '1018,1020,1021'` which it is

Turn it round, use LIKE and it will work (and be 1000x more efficient)

```
where CONTENT LIKE '%1018%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You are storing numeric values as a comma-delimited list.  This is a really bad idea.  You should have a table with one row per `ContentId`.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In this case, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table1 t
WHERE ',' + Content + ',' LIKE '%,' + '1018' + ',%';
```

The commas ensure that `'10'` does not match `'1018'`.

Note:  this format precludes the use of indexes, so hopefully your table is not too big.

Comment: this query will only return the second row , this is wrong

Answer (score 1):

According to comments you have to split comma separated list and use values. Something like this.

```
declare @tbl table(id int,content varchar(100))
insert @tbl values
(1,'1018'),
(2,'1018,1020'),
(3,'1021,1018,1022'),
(4,'1019')

--elaborate a little more
declare @val varchar(10)='1018'

;with cte as (
select id, cast('<s>'+ replace(content,',','</s><s>')+'</s>' as xml) content
from @tbl
)
select t.* from @tbl t
inner join cte on t.id=cte.id
cross apply cte.content.nodes('s[.=sql:variable("@val")]') x(v)
```